# Dask Workers lifetime option not waiting for job to finish

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

When applying workers lifetime option with restart, looks like if the worker is running a job, it still moves ahead with restart.

Applied lifetime restart option for every 60 secs using 1 worker and ran a job which simply sleeps for twice the amount of time. The restart still appears to take place even if the worker is running the job.

For graceful restart, thought the worker would wait for a long running task / job to finish and when idle would then restart itself. That way even if you have along running task its not interrupted by the auto restart option.

Comment: This sounds like you want to raise a feature request.  I recommend raising an issue on github.

Comment: Created github request - https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/3141